# What causes "Module parse failed" and how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, admin-on-rest

I created a project with `create-react-app` and I am using this app with the `admin-on-rest` package.

When I run `yarn start`, I get this error message:

```
./~/admin-on-rest/src/mui/input/TextInput.js
Module parse failed: 

/path/to/app/Resources/backend/node_modules/admin-on-rest/src/mui/input/TextInput.js Unexpected token (21:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  */
| export class TextInput extends Component {
|     handleBlur = (eventOrValue) => {
|         this.props.onBlur(eventOrValue);
|         this.props.input.onBlur(eventOrValue);
```

The line that causes that error message is :

```
|     handleBlur = (eventOrValue) => {
```

Which loader should I add? And how can I add it?

Comment: check this: http://discuss.babeljs.io/t/react-on-es6-unexpected-token-error-using-es7-property-initializer/327 and this one also: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties

Comment: @MayankShukla I did `yarn eject`, then added the dependency with `yarn add babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`. I edited my `package.json` to add `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` to the list of plugins. I re-run `yarn start` and I still got the same error message

Comment: My IDE created imports from the "admin-on-rest/src/..." directory and not from the transpiled version. Thus creating this bug.